# Htaccess redirect "www" and static subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I got htaccess with redirect from mysite.com to www.mysite.com :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But i have a subdomain static.mysite.com and I need to change htaccess to avoid redirect : static.mysite.com to www.static.mysite.com.

I'm very low in regular expresions. Can somebody help me?

(Sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|static)\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```